# Using Join and Between to Link Tables and Find Values

Tags: sql, join, between

I am trying to join these two tables and get a result, keep all results from Table 1 and find the value from Table 2 (return NULL if nothing is found in Table 2 matching criteria)

TABLE1

```
|ROUTE|MEASURE|
|:---:|:-----:|
|1|6|
|1|12|
|2|1|
|3|2|
|3|5|
```

TABLE2

```
|ROUTE|BEGINMEASURE|ENDMEASURE|VALUE|
|:---:|:-----:|:--:|:--:|
|1|0|5|A|
|1|5|10|B|
|2|0|5|C|
|3|0|3|D|
|3|3|10|E|
|3|10|12|F|
```

My code is:

```
select t1.route, t1.measure, t2.value  
from table1 t  
left join table2 t2 on t1.route=t2.route  
where t1.route=t2.route and t1.measure between t2.beginmeasure and t2.endmeasure;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition to the join:

```
select t1.route, t1.measure, t2.value  
from table1 t  
left join table2 t2 on t1.route=t2.route and t1.measure between t2.beginmeasure and t2.endmeasure;
```